# Is My Monitor Starting To Go?

Tags: display, video, hardware-failure

I've had this monitor for just about 7 and a half years now (it was made in August 2007) and every time it comes back on after my computer has been in sleep mode, it would flicker and now sometimes it will flicker and then the screen will go dark and you can faintly make out that it's the login screen (until I turn the monitor off and on and then its fixed). I've checked the connection and it is secure so that doesn't seem to be the problem. I have two monitors hooked up and the other one doesn't have this problem so I'm also thinking it's not the graphics card and/or driver. The monitor that I'm having this problem with is a Samsung 216BW and it is connected via DVI-D. The refresh rate is 60Hz and I can't change it to anything else. I'm wondering if this is a sign that the monitor is failing? If so, is there anything I can do to prolong it from completely failing and when will I know that I need a new monitor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is likely happening, as you can make out the faint display, is that the backlight of the monitor is failing.  That may be a florescent tube or LED.  Try connecting only that monitor to your system and cycle a few times between power saving and on.  If the behavior persists then it is very likely a hardware problem.  I am assuming it is a flat-screen monitor.  CRT monitors, the very old style, are completely different beasts.  You can bring the monitor into a shop to get the backlight replaced however the cost of doing so would probably be better spent on just getting a new monitor.  Being locked to 60Hz refresh rate is normal.  Monitors contain what is called "EDID" information which is a list of modes and refresh rates that the monitor supports.  That is read by your operating system and that will not let you choose anything that is out-of-range for the monitor.  If the monitor has previously supported different refresh rates and now doesn't then that is an indication that you may need a monitor driver for yours - although needing that is extremely rare today.